# Android - How can I prepopulating data in Room Database in kotlin (updated)?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I have a database in Room Kotlin (Android) like this, but I cannot prepopulate because never enter in **.addCallback(CALLBACK)**, how can I do this?

```
@Database(entities = [Entry::class, Category::class], version = 2, exportSchema = false)
@TypeConverters(RoomTypeConverters::class)
abstract class FinDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract val entryDao: EntryDao

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: FinDatabase? = null
        fun getInstance(context: Context): FinDatabase {
            synchronized(this) {
                var instance = INSTANCE
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                        context.applicationContext,
                        FinDatabase::class.java,
                        "database"
                    )
                        .addCallback(CALLBACK)
                        .addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2)
                        .build()
                    INSTANCE = instance
                }
                return instance
            }
        }

        private val CALLBACK = object : RoomDatabase.Callback() {
            override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                super.onCreate(db)
                db.execSQL("INSERT CATEGORY (id, name) VALUES (1, \"TESTE\") ")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see that the query is wrong.
Please change your query to:

```
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO CATEGORY (id, name) VALUES (1, 'TESTE')")
```

Note: 
CALLBACK's onCreate() will be called only once (i.e) when the database is created (At the first run). You will have to uninstall and re-run the app to get the callback getting triggered again.

Comment: But independent that, what happens is that the method **.addCallback(CALLBACK)** is never called.. and never execute db.execSQL

Comment: @JohnnyFagundes Okay. CALLBACK's onCreate() will be called only once (i.e) when the database is created (At the first run). You will have to uninstall and re-run the app to get the callback getting triggered again.

Comment: Ok Badhrinath Canessane, now I got it and it worked perfectly .. I though that I just play on **Run App** was work, but after uninstall and re-run has worked.. Thanks Man

Comment: In a very similar scenario, how can I use the DAO instances, I get an error when the DAO instance try to inserta data, I'm using execSQL... but I will like to use dao instances ... this is the error:  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getDatabase called recursively